# A generic composition with ambiguity detection

Tags: haskell, composition, typeerror, synonym

I want to define a generic composition which works both for `a -> b` and for `a -> Maybe b`:

```
class Comp m where
    (...) :: m a b -> m b c -> m a c

instance Comp (->) where
    (...) = (>>>)

instance Comp (a -> Maybe b) where
    (...) = (>=>)
```

Is it possible with all recent GHC extensions to define the second instance without a `newtype` wrapper similar to `Control.Arrow.Kleisli`?

Another problem is that the instances overlap, so for `Just ... Just` two equally sensible instances are possible. Is it possible to redesign `...` so `Just ... Just` has polymorphic type so both `a -> Maybe (Maybe a)` and `a -> Maybe a` are valid typings for it?

If it's not possible maybe it's possible to defer implementation selection somehow. E.g.

```
data Comp a b = Comp a b

(...) = Comp
($$$) =
```

`($$$)` lifts generic compositions (which can be anything - not necessarily functions) to functions. Then `Just ... Just $$$ (fromJust . fromJust)`

Comment: Type classes are a way of choosing an implementation of a function given its type. If there are two good implementations of that function for a particular type, classes are not the way to go!

Comment: Is there any other way to go?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not what you are looking for, but it will allow the instances to be defined.  Explicit type annotations will often be required to select the appropriate instance.  Using your example, `Just ... Just` is typed as `Comp (->) a (Maybe a) b (Maybe b) => a -> Maybe b`.  `FunctionalDependencies` *might* help on cutting down when explicit type annotations are required, but would also restrict the possible instances to less than what you would like.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
import Control.Category
import Control.Monad

class Comp m a b b' c where
  (...) :: m a b -> m b' c -> m a c

instance Comp (->) a b b c where
  (...) = (>>>)

instance Monad m => Comp (->) a (m b) b (m c) where
  (...) = (>=>)
```